# update statement error in Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to update several columns in a table called "tbl_Responses" but it gives an error after running which I have been trying to find!

```
varX= DLookup("[ID]", tableName, "[supplierNum] = " & supplierNum)
updateFieldsTbl1="column1,column2,column3,column4"
updateValuesTbl1 ="name,lastname, bla bla"
'There is nothing wrong with those 3 variables above.


sqlUp = "UPDATE " & tableName & "(" & updateFieldsTbl1 & ")" & " SET " & "(" & _ updateValuesTbl1 & ") WHERE ID = " & varX
DoCmd.RunSQL sqlUp
```

It gives an error in UPDATE statement line.
Can you please tell what I am doing wrong?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string parses to:

```
UPDATE tableName (column1,column2,column3,column4) SET (name,lastname, bla bla) ...
```

Which is similar to the `INSERT` format which is not valid for an `UPDATE`, the correct format is:

```
UPDATE tableName 
SET column1 = 'name',
    column2 = 'lastname',
    columnN =  valueN
WHERE ID = X
```

build the string thusly and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

That's the syntax for an INSERT - for an UPDATE it's

```
UPDATE Table SET Field1=Value1, Field2=Value2, etc WHERE ...
```